# WAMP using Windows 10 in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, dll, virtual-machine, virtualbox, wamp

I want to install a Web server and analyze the processing of the requests, to verify the relationship between the configurations and the behavior of the server.

In order to be able to deliver my configuration, I've decided to *develop the entire task in a VirtualBox virtual machine*.

The process I've been through was straightforward:

1. Install the [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) virtualizer.
2. Download a [free Windows 10 virtual machine](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) for testing (runs
   for 90 days).
3. Download and install the [Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64 /
   86.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) and the [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) package on the virtual machine.
   (To drag files to the virtual machine, go to Devices > Drag)

As I'm using a 64 bit version of Windows 10, decided to *install a WAMP x64*.

Initially, the errors I've been through were:

> vcruntime140.dll
>
> msvcr120.dll
>
> msvcp120.dll

After going through them all, copying the .dll to the folder System32, no .dll was missing anylonger and still appeared the following error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b).

At this time i thought: well, *if WAMP x64 doesn't work, let's try WAMP x32*.

Turns out the errors showing up were (just like previously in *WAMP x64*):

> vcruntime140.dll
>
> msvcr120.dll
>
> msvcp120.dll

Accordingly to one of [WAMPS's forum moderators](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295), *RiggsFolly*, it's crucial to:

> -- Make sure your system has "up to date" versions of ALL these redistributable packages:-
>
> --- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2008 (VC9),
>
> --- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2010 (VC10),
>
> --- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2012 (VC11),
>
> --- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2013 (VC13),
>
> --- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2015 (VC14),
>
> --- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2017 (VC15)

After doing it and trying to install *WAMP x64* i get the same result as before.

Based also on *RiggsFolly* post in the forum:

> -- Wampserver 3.1.3 32/64 bit x86_x64 (Cumulative Update.) You are strongly encouraged to apply this update. This is a cumulative update.
> There is no need to apply the old updates 3.0.1 to 3.1.2 before
> applying 3.1.3. This update will be required to install the latest
> Apache, PHP, MySQL or MariaDB addons.

I've done that but the problem persists... testing atm installing *WAMP x32*.

This seems to me I'm in a circle and the installation of WAMP, due to my machine requisites, can take up to 30 min - it's just to much time waiting. This should be quite straightforward, i don't get it...

**How can I complete the installation of WAMP with success?**

Comment: don't manually copy dlls to system32, you're just asking for trouble. The 0x7b suggests you copied the wrong bit-ness to system32. System32 is for 64-bit DLLs on a 64-bit version of Windows, but for 32-bit DLLs on a 32-bit version of Windows

Comment: well I just did it without involving any copy of .dll's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked using *WAMP x32* (and ofc granting all the previous redistributable packages - x 86 only was enough).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a missing DLL files error the following simple fix may solve the issue.

Open CMD and paste the following:

```
sfc /scannow
```

One needs to wait a bit for the process to complete, but the problem should be solved.

---

**Edit**: If the process above doesn't solve, do this first:
1 - Uninstall WAMP
2 - Install all the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages (2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017)
3 - Reinstall WAMP

Then redo the process above and you have all the .dll (this may not even be required to have all the services up and running with no errors).